# Automated URL Discovering

Tags: web-application, brute-force

I built a simple server containing static files at `/files/` and I'm attempting to discover them using automated tools.

I'm using [wfuzz](https://code.google.com/p/wfuzz) to brute force on the URL but is that the only way? Is there any other method for URL discovery, probably more effective that could compromise the privacy of my server?

What other techniques do hackers use on the wild?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Discovery of URLs in the wild tends to be done in one of three ways

1. Search Engine Based.  If your content gets indexed by a search engine, it's discoverable.  this doesn't just include them hitting your site directly, if other sites link to the content it may be findable that way.
2. "known URLS".  There's a lot of URLs that are known to be things like administrative interfaces or CGIs with known issues.  Tools like [nikto](http://cirt.net/Nikto2) maintain a database of them and can be used by attackers to discover systems which have that software installed.
3. Brute-force.  Tools like [OWASP DirBuster](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_DirBuster_Project) combined with lists of common directory/file names can be used to discover content.

In terms of an untargeted attack unless you have a common vulnerable piece of software (e.g. phpmyadmin) hosted on a default URL, it's unlikely you'll have a problem as the sheer number of sites on the Internet make it unlikely that you'll face a human attacker focused on finding content on your site.

With a targeted attacker tools like nikto and dirbuster would be usuable to try and find content on your site.

If you have information that you don't want to be found I would recommend adding authentication and SSL to it to prevent unauthorised access to it.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to use a tool called ZAP, it contains a fork of DirBuster. You can use dictionary forced browsing to try common urls.

ZAP is a free tool from OWASP